# For time varying linear ODEs: is there a transformation which can make the system admit an exponential solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

First, I'll start with the properties of the matrix in question:

Assume we are given some matrix $\mathbf{A}(t)$, which is time dependent. This matrix is square and not invertible.

A system:
$$
\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$

Admits the solution:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}(0)\text{exp}\left({\int^t_0\mathbf{A}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau}\right)
$$

If the following property holds:

$$
\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{A}(\tau)=\mathbf{A}(\tau)\mathbf{A}(t)
$$

Otherwise, there needs to be some time ordering scheme used to find the solution, since the matrix does not commute with itself at different times.

The property is also know as the matrix being *semi-proper*.

Now, is there some transformation, such as $\mathbf{z}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),t)$, where the new system would admit an exponential solution as:

$$
\mathbf{z}(t)=\mathbf{z}(0)\text{exp}\left(\boldsymbol{\Omega}(t)\right)
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\Omega}(t)$ can be solved analytically when $\mathbf{A}(t)$ is *not* semi-proper?

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information than that.  What do you know about $A$?  What do you know about $B$?  Why isn't $B(t) = I$ a valid solution?

Comment: @DanielV: I should have been more specific about what I actually wanted, I thought I could ask the question without giving too much background to avoid confusion, but I think I sort of defeated the purpose of the question in doing that (and also phrased the question wrong). I've reworked the question considerably to make it clearer.

Comment: I think you should summarize your question to begin with:  "Is there a solution to $$\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)$$ when $A$ is a matrix but not semi proper?"  Everything after that is details.

Comment: @DanielV: I'm specifically interested in exponential solutions, although I might just delete this question and write a new one as you've written it.

Comment: I did some looking around, and if it has a solution then it is probably in terms of the eigenvalues $\lambda_n(t)$ and eigenvectors $u_n(t)$, there may be some sort of exponential solution in terms of those that you can tease out.

Comment: That's possible, I've seen something also relating the solution to what's called a "Magnus Expansion", which can be derived using Picard iteration. I'll look more tomorrow.